# Where can I find a full copy of Philip K Dick's Exegesis?

Tags: philip-k-dick

I've heard recently that [a 90% reduced Fat version of the Exegesis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0547549253) was going to come out in print. However, I would really like to get a hold of a full copy. They aren't supposed to exist, however, years hence perhaps they will.

So greetings future people. Please grace me with a means to read this no-doubt fascinating romp down the rabbit-hole of religiously-fueled psychobabble.

Comment: @RANSARA009 Please don't make bad edits. Your own posts suggest that you haven't completely mastered capitalisation rules in English yourself, so please don't try to 'correct' other people's capitalisation until you have.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Why is these post even here? Why hasn't it been closed and deleted in the past five years?? And it even has upvotes??? Aren't wanted-to-buy ads considered spam????

Comment: @user14111 I'm not sure. This question was asked on the very first day of private beta, when site scope and standards were different. Feel free to VTC and/or ask about this question on meta.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Some background. This is not a WTB post. It was an experiment. It emerged from an early discussion about what the site could and couldn't support. We wanted to see if we could ask questions about resources we KNEW didn't exist and see if they might appear and be answered in the deep future. Could SE sites handle this? This was part of a host of other similar questions I asked around the same time. Many of them could probably be closed. I was Mod-Pro-Tem then. Feel free to delete this comment after reading and clean or delete this question as you see fit. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the information on the [Philip K. Dick Exegesis page](http://www.philipkdick.com/new_exegesis.html)....

> Although Philip K. Dick's In the
>   Pursuit of VALIS: Selections from the
>   Exegesis was published in the year
>   1991, there remain thousands of
>   unpublished pages from this mostly
>   handwritten journal. It contains
>   autobiographical material,
>   philosophical speculation and analysis
>   of his own fiction. Due to the
>   continuing interest in these
>   unpublished pages, the Philip K. Dick
>   Trust will be releasing additional
>   volumes from the vast collection.
>   **These writings will be exclusive to
>   PhilipKDick.com**. Please visit
>   regularly to see the most recent
>   releases.

....It does not look like a full copy of Exegesis will be published. Rats.

Comment: I know. But maybe in the distant future. If you find out more in 5 years, come add a new answer. :)

Comment: @DampeS8N: I kinda figured you had looked at the site...I thought the casual reader might like a bit of info anyway :) Five years ?..Maybe. Dick is always a late bloomer...I'd bet 10.

Comment: As would any Dickhead, I can't wait!

Comment: Mhh, the site is down now.

Comment: Almost 8 years later, still no way to get it. :(