# Philip K. Dick Essay

Tags: short-stories, philip-k-dick

Does anyone have any clue where I can find (in any format, although physical would be preferred) an essay written in 1964 (at least according to [this](http://www.philipkdick.com/works_other.html) site) by Philip K. Dick, that goes by the name of "Tips for the Beginning Writer"?

Comment: Shopping questions (i.e. where can I get this?) are discouraged on Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: I didn't mean for the question to be a shopping question. Rather, I was wondering IF there is any way to get a hold of it. Either a physical copy or a digital one.

Comment: and why, just to satisfy my curiosity, is my question regarded as a shopping question when this one (http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31/where-can-i-find-a-full-copy-of-philip-k-dicks-exegesis?rq=1) is not?

Comment: This would be reasonable of chat, btw. It's not that people here don't want to help you, just that this is not a good entry for the Q&A. Alas, I can offer no suggestions.

Comment: @Keen Shopping questions are discouraged when it's a matter of comparing products or suppliers. This isn't the case here: the question asks where to find something that an official site claims exist but for which neither ISFDB nor Google turns up any source. We normally welcome this kind of bibliographic reference question. I'm reopening.

Answer (score 5):

[Paul Williams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Williams_%28Crawdaddy!_creator%29), author of "Only Apparently Real:The World of Philip K. Dick", may be your best source when it comes to finding some of the [lesser known writings of Philip K. Dick](http://www.philipkdick.com/works_other.html). I was able to locate him in the King County Library System.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but according to Paul Williams' site he suffered "a traumatic brain injury in a bicycle accident, leading to early onset of dementia, and a steady decline to the point where he now requires full-time care.". So I'm guessing he won't, unfortunately, be able to help me much.

Comment: But the books he wrote are still available. Good luck on your quest! :)

Comment: Thank you! And I found a contacts page on the official PKD site and mailed them about it. Waiting for a reply!

Comment: @JNat: Once you have a reply, do answer your own question... If you can.  ^_~

Comment: @Sardathrion: they never replied... so I do not have any answer yet.

Comment: @JNat How goes the quest? :)

Comment: @MajorStackings: I actually haven't looked in a while. The mail I sent to the official PKD site never got an answer. Now that same site is down. Paul Williams' site has no contacts. And I haven't spent much time looking for it elsewhere... The only other guess I have, is that it may be in [this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Only-Apparently-Real-Paul-Williams/dp/0934558310/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1357912891&sr=8-1), since I get the impression (from comments on Amazon) that it is a compilation of articles and interviews, but I am not not sure if **by** or **on** PKD...